# MYSQL parent relations

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child, parent

I have this table structured like this

```
CATEGORIE

id name categorie_id
```

Some categories are nested so categorie 1 is going to be in categorie 2 and categorie 3.

I would like to display all the names of categories and also their attributed parents in a query.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join with self.

```
select t1.name, t2.name as parent_name 
from categories t1 
left join categories t2 on t1.parent_id = t2.id
```

Change `categorie_id` to `parent_id` for more readable.

Comment: Looks great. What happens when it's a sub sub category ? Is there a way to get both parents too ?

Comment: @Kiwimoisi You need another join.